# Why is the backgroundworker not pausing when I click the button?

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form1 I removed/deleted the _busy variable. In Form1 top I did:

```
BackgroundWebCrawling bgwc;
```

Then in the button4 pause click event I did:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bgwc.PauseWorker();
    label6.Text = "Process Paused";
    button5.Enabled = true;
    button4.Enabled = false;
}
```

In the button5 click event button I did:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bgwc.ContinueWorker();
    label6.Text = "Process Resumed";
    button4.Enabled = true;
    button5.Enabled = false;
}
```

And the cancel button click event:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bgwc.CancelWorker();
    cancel = true;
}
```

Then I'm checking in Form1 completed event if cancel is true or not:

```
if (cancel == true)
{
    label6.Text = "Process Cancelled";
}
else
{
    label6.Text = "Process Completed";
}
```

And this is how the BackgroundWebCrawling class look like now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    class BackgroundWebCrawling
    {
        public string f;
        int counter = 0;
        List<string> WebSitesToCrawl;
        int MaxSimultaneousThreads;
        public BackgroundWorker mainBackGroundWorker;
        BackgroundWorker secondryBackGroundWorker;
        WebcrawlerConfiguration webcrawlerCFG;
        List<WebCrawler> webcrawlers;
        int maxlevels;
        public event EventHandler<BackgroundWebCrawlingProgressEventHandler> ProgressEvent;
        ManualResetEvent _busy = new ManualResetEvent(true);

        public BackgroundWebCrawling()
        {
            webcrawlers = new List<WebCrawler>();
            mainBackGroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            mainBackGroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            mainBackGroundWorker.DoWork += mainBackGroundWorker_DoWork;
        }

        private void mainBackGroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            for (int i = 0; i < WebSitesToCrawl.Count; i++)
            {
                _busy.WaitOne();
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                while (counter >= MaxSimultaneousThreads)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }

                WebCrawler wc = new WebCrawler(webcrawlerCFG);
                webcrawlers.Add(wc);
                counter++;
                secondryBackGroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
                secondryBackGroundWorker.DoWork += secondryBackGroundWorker_DoWork;
                object[] args = new object[] { wc, WebSitesToCrawl[i] };
                secondryBackGroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(args);
            }
            while (counter > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }

        private void secondryBackGroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            object[] args = (object[])e.Argument;
            WebCrawler wc = (WebCrawler)args[0];
            string mainUrl = (string)args[1];
            wc.ProgressEvent += new EventHandler<WebCrawler.WebCrawlerProgressEventHandler>(x_ProgressEvent);
            wc.webCrawler(mainUrl, maxlevels);

            counter--;
        }

        public void Start(List<string> sitestocrawl, int threadsNumber, int maxlevels, WebcrawlerConfiguration wccfg)
        {
            this.maxlevels = maxlevels;
            webcrawlerCFG = wccfg;
            WebSitesToCrawl = sitestocrawl;
            MaxSimultaneousThreads = threadsNumber;
            mainBackGroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void x_ProgressEvent(object sender, WebCrawler.WebCrawlerProgressEventHandler e)
        {
            // OK .. so now you get the data here in e
            // and here you should call the event to form1
            Object[] temp_arr = new Object[8];
            temp_arr[0] = e.csFiles;
            temp_arr[1] = e.mainUrl;
            temp_arr[2] = e.levels;
            temp_arr[3] = e.currentCrawlingSite;
            temp_arr[4] = e.sitesToCrawl;
            temp_arr[5] = e.done;
            temp_arr[6] = e.failedUrls;
            temp_arr[7] = e.failed;
            OnProgressEvent(temp_arr); /// Send the data + additional data from this class to Form1..
                                       ///
            /*
             * temp_arr[0] = csFiles;
                temp_arr[1] = mainUrl;
                temp_arr[2] = levels;
                temp_arr[3] = currentCrawlingSite;
                temp_arr[4] = sitesToCrawl;*/
        }

        private void GetLists(List<string> allWebSites)
        {

        }

        public class BackgroundWebCrawlingProgressEventHandler : EventArgs
        {
            public List<string> csFiles { get; set; }
            public string mainUrl { get; set; }
            public int levels { get; set; }
            public List<string> currentCrawlingSite { get; set; }
            public List<string> sitesToCrawl { get; set; }
            public bool done { get; set; }
            public int failedUrls { get; set; }
            public bool failed { get; set; }
        }

        protected void OnProgressEvent(Object[] some_params) // Probably you need to some vars here to...
        {
            // some_params to put in evenetArgs..
            if (ProgressEvent != null)
                ProgressEvent(this,
                    new BackgroundWebCrawlingProgressEventHandler()
                    {
                        csFiles = (List<string>)some_params[0],
                        mainUrl = (string)some_params[1],
                        levels = (int)some_params[2],
                        currentCrawlingSite = (List<string>)some_params[3],
                        sitesToCrawl = (List<string>)some_params[4],
                        done = (bool)some_params[5],
                        failedUrls = (int)some_params[6],
                        failed = (bool)some_params[7]
                    });
        }

        public void PauseWorker()
        {
            if (mainBackGroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                _busy.Reset();
            }
        }

        public void ContinueWorker()
        {
            _busy.Set();
        }

        public void CancelWorker()
        {
            ContinueWorker();
            mainBackGroundWorker.CancelAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

So I added the methods the pause the continue the cancel. In the dowork event, I changed all the things and added things.

But when I click the buttons there is no effect. Not pausing, not continue and not cancel. Nothing.

Comment: And how `ManualResetEventHandle` relates with `BackgroundWorker`. To cancel worker you must use its built-in capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never check the `_busy` status in `mainBackGroundWorker_DoWork` method;

```
for (int i = 0; i < WebSitesToCrawl.Count; i++)
{
    _busy.WaitOne();
    //...
}
```

also you should have your `ManualResetEvent _busy` in class with BackgroundWorker

```
ManualResetEvent _busy = new ManualResetEvent(true);
public BackgroundWorker mainBackGroundWorker;

public void PauseWorker()
{
   if(mainBackGroundWorker.IsBusy)
   {
        _busy.Reset(); 
   }
}

public void ContinueWorker()
{
    _busy.Set();
}
```

and in `Form1`:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bgwc.PauseWorker();
    //...
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bgwc.ContinueWorker();
    //...
}
```

to cancel the BackgroundWorker you can use `CancellationPending` property and `CancelAsync` method. Note: you should first unpause the worker.

```
public void CancelWorker()
{
   ContinueWorker();
   mainBackGroundWorker.CancelAsync();
}

private void mainBackGroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    for (int i = 0; i < WebSitesToCrawl.Count; i++)
    {
        _busy.WaitOne();
         if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
         {
             e.Cancel = true;
             break;
         }
         //...
    }  
}
```

If this doesn't help you, then you have problems with `mainBackGroundWorker` code and `secondryBackGroundWorker`.

1. This code only pauses mainBackGroundWorker, but not secondryBackGroundWorkers. The same with cancelation. If main worker is canceled? it  will wait for all the secondary workers to finish their jobs. Also if you pause main worker? you can still have new results arriving from secondary workers.
2. You do not handle errors. If you have an exception in second worker, than you do not get any notification about that and also your main worker will never stop, because `counter` will never be `0`.
3. There can be another problems, witch cause this behaviour.

Comment: Dmitry the code with the _busy.WaitOne(); is that the cancel of the operation ?

Comment: @user2760148 No, _busy.WaitOne() wait for the thread to be unpaused. I updated the answer with cancelation code.

Comment: Dmitry nothing . Its not working. I will update my question with the current code how i did it.

Comment: Dmitry updated my question with the current code after the changes i did. Please take a look on it and show me the fixed code how is it suppose to be ? Thanks.

Comment: @user2760148 i have created simple winForm with my code to proof it works. https://code.google.com/p/backgroundworker-example/ and also updater my answer